# ImportError: cannot import name '_path' matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror

When importing matplotlib by `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "mode.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   File "C:\Users\yuhan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar   File "C:\Users\yuhan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist   File "C:\Users\yuhan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .path import Path   File "C:\Users\yuhan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import _path, rcParams ImportError: cannot import name '_path'
```

I tried reinstalling the whole matplotlib library, tried re-installing Python 3.6 etc. I really do not know what is wrong and since I don't have a backup.

Comment: managed to fix it by reinstalling the whole matplotlib module.

`py -m pip uninstall matplotlib` and then
`py -m pip install matplotlib`

Answer (score 13):

```
py -m pip uninstall matplotlib
```

then:

```
py -m pip install matplotlib
```

worked for me for that error as well.

Then I had a problem of kiwisolver not being found, and did the same
uninstall, install for kiwisolver and now:
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` works.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can pop up when you copy libraries from place to place (at least that's what happend with me :P)

Make sure that in *.../Python37/Lib/site-packages* there is a file named:
**matplotlib-3.0.2-py3.7-nspkg.pth**
with the correct version of Python and matplotlib

(in this example I am using python 3.7.1 and matplotlib 3.0.2)

If that's not the case, reinstall matplotlib like other users suggested.
Make sure also that you are targeting the correct directory (sometimes I've seen that the problem might be the wrong version of pip)